# Apache 2.4 graceful restart is killing connections

Tags: apache

I have RHEL7.2 with Apache 2.4.6 (From the RHEL repository) using the `event-mpm`. When I do a graceful restart using the following command, active connections are terminated.

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -f /path/to/httpd.conf -k graceful
```

Everything I have read suggests that this should not be the case. Any worker processes/threads should complete their active connections before being terminated and replaced by a new worker with the new config.

I tested this by using `JMeter` and by using `ab` on some 'large' files (~15Mb). I was seeing the problem on small 1Kb files also, but I was only able to reliably reproduce the problem on JMeter and not from ab. Using the larger file highlights the problem more reliably as there is a higher chance of the reload happening during an active connection.

For more background, I was originally thinking that the behaviour I was seeing from `JMeter` (but not from `ab`) was new connections failing during the brief time that the master listening process was reloading and refusing new connections. This did not make sense as the OS is meant to queue the new connections. This is when I investigated the possibility that it was killing existing connections and tried with the larger files.

Any thoughts on what may be going on here, how I can test further and possibly how to resolve?

Here is the Apache info, if it helps:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built:   Jul 12 2016 05:02:54
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I don't recall. I can go back to look at my work e-mails if needed. Are you having the same problem?

Looking back on the above question, I can't help thinking that it would be helpful if I had more 'proof' that the requests were actually getting killed.

Comment: I have a hole of missing work e-mails from the end of 2016, so I got nothin'. Sorry :(